# How to use Memcpy() function

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I want to use the memcpy in the end, instead of

```
block_orig_left[i1][j1]=block_orig[i1][j1];
pred_orig_left [i1][j1]=block_pred[i1][j1];
```

I have an error using memcpy

> src/coder.c:909: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int **’)
>   src/coder.c:910: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int **’)

```
int **block_orig_left=NULL;

block_orig_left=intmatrix(BSIZE_Y_LEVEL[levelv], BSIZE_X_LEVEL[levelv]);
pred_orig_left=intmatrix(BSIZE_Y_LEVEL[levelv], BSIZE_X_LEVEL[levelv]);

for(i1=0; i1<BSIZE_Y_LEVEL[levelv]; i1++)
for(j1=0; j1<BSIZE_X_LEVEL[levelv]; j1++)
{
    block_orig_left[i1][j1]=block_orig[i1][j1];
    pred_orig_left[i1][j1]=block_pred[i1][j1];
    Average_block_orig_left+=block_orig[i1][j1];        
} 
memcpy(block_orig_left, block_orig, sizeof(int **)*block_orig);

memcpy(pred_orig_left, block_pred,  sizeof(int **)*block_pred);
```

How do I use the memcpy correctly?

Comment: You're multiplying a pointer by an unsigned int. You can't do that (and you don't want to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are multiplying the size of an int** by an int**, which doesn't make sense. In other words, if you wanted to know the weight of all the cars on a truck, you can't multiply "weight of 1 car" by "truck". You have to multiply the weight of 1 car by the number of cars on the truck.

The third parameter to memcpy is the number of bytes you want to copy. You are correctly getting the size of an int**, but then you want to multiply that by the number of int** in the structure. So, if I'm understanding your code correctly, you would want to use

```
sizeof(int**) * BSIZE_Y_LEVEL[levelv] * BSIZE_X_LEVEL[levelv]
```

since the structures you are copying seem to contain that many int double pointers.

EDIT: Looking at David Yaw's answer, I realize that he is correct. I failed to address the fact that the inner pointers were likely not all allocated at once, but rather in a for loop or something, so they would need to be copied in like manner. My way above would copy the right amount of memory, but it would not necessarily be the correct memory.

Comment: Thanks guys, that is the correct way to do it. I had already made that, just posted the wrong code. I doesnt give an error anymore but the program doesnt work properly. Thanks anyway

Comment: As I mentioned in my edit, look at David Yaw's answer. He had a better answer than mine, because I forgot that you probably allocated each of the sub-arrays individually, in a for loop or something. That means they probably aren't contiguous, and need to each be memcpy'd individually. And you should be using sizeof(int), not sizeof(int**) since you are counting the ints, the int** is just what's pointing to them. Though in most cases, that will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that block_orig, block_pred, block_orig_left, and pred_orig_left are all declared as `int**`. Only one of them is shown in your code.

The error that you're getting is in the parameter to memcpy, `sizeof(int **)*block_orig`. You're trying to multiply an integer (`sizeof(int**)`) with a variable of type int**. The compiler can't make sense of that multiplication.

You need to fix your length parameter to memcpy, but that still won't work as desired.

```
// Still won't work.
memcpy(block_orig_left, block_orig, sizeof(int) * BSIZE_Y_LEVEL[levelv] * BSIZE_X_LEVEL[levelv]);
```

An `int**` is an array of pointers to arrays of integers. If you tried to memcpy the int**, you'll end up overwriting the outer array. Therefore, I think you need a loop and copy the inner arrays.

This should work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < BSIZE_Y_LEVEL[levelv]; i++)
{
    memcpy(block_orig_left[i], block_orig[i], sizeof(int) * BSIZE_X_LEVEL[levelv]);
}
```

Comment: Multiplying by sizeof(int) would not necessarily be correct, since an int does not have to be the same size as a pointer. I believe. :) I think he was correct to use sizeof(int**).

Comment: He's trying to copy the data, not the pointers to the storage. I think sizeof(int) is correct, but the int** means a single memcpy won't do it. See edit.

Comment: Ah, true. I was misunderstanding his data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy(block_orig_left, block_orig, sizeof(int **)*block_orig);
```

`sizeof(int **)*block_orig` is the multiplication of a size with a pointer. I guess you know that multiplying a pointer doesn't make sense nor is it possible as you can see from the compiler error.

I don't know what `block_orig` or your other (btw did you hear about self-describing variable names?) variables mean, but [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memcpy.html) takes the target, the source, and the size in bytes as arguments.

In your integer-matrix case, something like `sizeof(int) * numberOfElementsToCopy` would make sense, if the target memory is continuous (i.e. 2D array).